# Problema al mostrar una lista de objetos

Tags: bucle-for, arraylist, objeto, class

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para un curso de Java y me quede estancado con un ejercicio de realizar una nomina para empleados, dichos datos que se piden son nombre, apellido, id, salario, estos que se cargan a un arraylist como objeto en clase secundaria de Empleados.

Codigo de la clase main

```
package Nomina;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nominas {
    private static Empleados eghp;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("*****TABACOS EL GRAN HUMO*****");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ 
        System.out.print("Ingrese nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.next().toUpperCase();
        System.out.print("Ingrese apellido: ");
        String apellido = sc.next().toUpperCase();
        System.out.print("Ingrese cedula: ");
        int cedula = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese Salario: ");
        double salario = sc.nextDouble();
        
        eghp = new Empleados(nombre, apellido, cedula, salario);
        //listaEmpleados.add(eghp);
        eghp.addEmpleado(nombre, apellido, cedula, salario);
        //eghp.imprimirEmpleados();
        /*System.out.println();
        System.out.print("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + eghp.getNombres() + " " + eghp.getApellidos());
        System.out.println("Cédula de ciudadanía: " + eghp.getCedulas());
        System.out.println("INGRESOS");
        System.out.println("Salario: " + eghp.AnalizadorSalario());
        eghp.opeNomina();*/
        eghp.imprimirEmpleados();
        }
        eghp.imprimirEmpleados();
    }
}
```

El ejercicio debe cumplir una serie de condiciones las cuales ya fueron realizadas, el programa al final pide mostrar un arraylist con los objetos que se agregan es decir (nombres, apellidos, cedula o id, salario) de cada trabajador registrado.

Adjunto el codigo de la segunda clase

```
package Nomina;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Empleados {

    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private int cedulas;
    private double salarios;
    private ArrayList <Empleados> listaEmpleados;

    public Empleados(String nombres, String apellidos, int cedulas, double salarios) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.cedulas = cedulas;
        this.salarios = salarios;
        this.listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setSalario(double salarios){
        this.salarios = salarios;
    }

    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public int getCedulas() {
        return cedulas;
    }

    public double getSalarios() {
        return salarios;
    }

    public double AnalizadorSalario(){
        double MIN = 908526;
        double sal = this.salarios;
        if (sal < MIN){
            sal = MIN;
        }
        return sal;
    }

    public void opeNomina(){

        double MIN = 908526;
        double sal = this.AnalizadorSalario();
        double aux = 0;
        double desSalyPen = 0;
        double desSolPen = 0;
        double total = 0;
        if (sal >= MIN && sal <= MIN*2){
            aux =+ 106454;
            desSalyPen = sal * 0.04;
            total = sal + aux - desSalyPen - desSalyPen;
            System.out.println("Auxilio de transporte: " + aux);
            System.out.println("DESCUENTOS");
            System.out.println("Aportes a salud: " + desSalyPen);
            System.out.println("Aportes a pensión: " + desSalyPen);
            System.out.println("TOTAL A PAGAR");
            System.out.println(total);
        }
        else if (sal > MIN*2 && sal < MIN*4){
            desSalyPen = sal * 0.04;
            total = sal - desSalyPen - desSalyPen;
            System.out.println("DESCUENTOS");
            System.out.println("Aportes a salud: " + desSalyPen);
            System.out.println("Aportes a pensión: " + desSalyPen);
            System.out.println("TOTAL A PAGAR");
            System.out.println(total);
        }
        else{
            desSalyPen = sal * 0.04;
            desSolPen = sal * 0.01;
            total = sal - desSalyPen - desSalyPen - desSolPen;
            System.out.println("DESCUENTOS");
            System.out.println("Aportes a salud: " + desSalyPen);
            System.out.println("Aportes a pensión: " + desSalyPen);
            System.out.println("Fondo de solidaridad pensional: " + desSolPen);
            System.out.println("TOTAL A PAGAR");
            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }

    public void addEmpleado(String nombres, String apellidos, int cedulas, double salarios){
        Empleados c = new Empleados(nombres, apellidos, cedulas, salarios);
        this.listaEmpleados.add(c);
    }

    public void imprimirEmpleados(){
        
        for(Empleados empleado : this.listaEmpleados){            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("-------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Nombre: " + getNombres() + " " + getApellidos());
            System.out.println("Cédula de ciudadanía: " + getCedulas());
            System.out.println("INGRESOS");
            System.out.println("Salario: " + AnalizadorSalario());
            opeNomina();
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo al momento de realizar la muestra final el programa solo me arroja los datos de la ultima persona que registre, agradezco me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo, cada instancia del objeto de empleado tiene internamente una lista con el mismo empleado, deberías crearte la lista en la clase "Nominas", por ejemplo:

```
private ArrayList <Empleados> listaEmpleados;
```

Y cada vez que crees un empleado lo añades en la lista:

```
Empleados empleado = new Empleados(nombre, apellido, cedula, salario);
listaEmpleados.add(empleado);
```

Para mostrarlos necesitarías tener la función "imprimirEmpleados()" en la clase "Nominas" y usar los "get" de la clase "Empleados" para mostrar los datos.

```
for(Empleados empleado : this.listaEmpleados){            
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("-------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Nombre: " + empleado.getNombres() + " " + empleado.getApellidos());
    System.out.println("Cédula de ciudadanía: " + empleado.getCedulas());
    System.out.println("INGRESOS");
    System.out.println("Salario: " + empleado.AnalizadorSalario());
    opeNomina();
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente amigo, realice esos cambios que me indicaste y funcionaron, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, lo que importa más es que hayas entendido el porque fallaba, si no es así te lo explico mejor.